# AngularJS. Добавление параметров из $scope в URL ui.router

Tags: angularjs

Всем привет!
Помогите, пож, в таком вопросе.

Использую для роутинга контента ui.router

перенаправление между вкладками выглядит примерно так -

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TabsCntr">
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
    <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" label="{{tab.title}}" ui-sref={  {tab.route}} active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled" select="go(tab.route)" ui-sref-active="tab.active">
      <ui-view ng-controller="InputCntr"></ui-view>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
</div>
```

Роутер :

```
function TabsRoute ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
// Angular Routing
  $stateProvider.state('date', {
    url: '/date',
    templateUrl: 'date.html',
    controller: 'TabsCntr'
  }).state('group', {
    url: '/group',
    templateUrl: 'group.html'
  }).state('attrs', {
    url: '/attrs',
    templateUrl: 'attrs.html'
  }).state('date.btn', {
    url: '/clientid=:clientid',
    templateUrl: 'tableview.html'
  }).state('group.btn', {
    url: '/show',
    templateUrl: 'tableview.html'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('date');
};
```

нуж в URL передвать параметр из $scope
типо

```
.state('date.btn', {<br>
  url: '/clientid=:$scope.groupItem.clientid',<br>
  templateUrl: 'tableview.html'<br>
})
```

для того чтобы параметры тянулись в урле после подгрузки контента (таблица которая строится на основании выполнения запроса к сервису).

пробовал подключать контроллер

```
controller($scope, $stateParams){
  $stateParams.clientid = $scope.groupItem.clientid;
}
```

всем мимо, не подтягивается в урл(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) позволяет передавать параметры для роута, для этого нужно использовать следующий синтаксис

```
ui-sref="routeName({paramName: paramValue})"
```

Comment: спасибо, я тупил и не по тому state пробовал передавать этот параметр)